# JavaScript to calculate random position for divs with no collision

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to draw a bunch of divs inside of a container in such a way that they are randomly positioned every time the page is loaded and that there is no overlapping. I seem to be stuck in an infinite loop and without the sources loading in Chrome before crashing the page, I can't debug properly.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var filledAreas = new Array();

  var minX = 50;
  var maxX = $("#banner").width() - 150;
  var minY = 50;
  var maxY = $("#banner").height() - 150;

  var loops = 0;
  var loopsMax = 100;

  for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    var color = '#' + Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
    $newDiv = $("<div class='bubble-outer'></div>").css({
      'width': '100px',
      'height': '100px',
      'background-color': color,
    });
    var randX = 0;
    var randY = 0;
    var area;
    do {
      randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxX - minX + 1)) + minX;
      randY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxY - minY + 1)) + minY;
      var area = {
        'left': randX,
        'top': randY,
        'right': randX + 100,
        'bottom': randY + 100,
      };
    } while (loops < loopsMax && checkOverlap(area))

    filledAreas.push(area)

    $newDiv.css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'left': randX + 'px',
      'top': randY + 'px',
      'display': 'none'
    }).delay(1000).appendTo("#banner").fadeIn(300);
  }

  console.log("Loops: " + loops);

  function checkOverlap(area) {
    for (var i = 0; i < filledAreas.length; i++) {
      var check = filledAreas[i];
      if (area.right < check.left && area.bottom < check.top &&
        check.right < area.left && check.bottom < area.top) {
        loops++;
        continue;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I suggest you use the debugger and step through the code to see what's going on. Currently it runs when the page loads, so you should instead find another way to trigger it. Perhaps use `document.onclick` or similar.

Comment: I implemented an algorithm for a particular feature on my site. I "cheated" by dividing the area into a grid and only allowing one element inside each grid space (if a grid space was already taken, a different one would be picked).

Comment: If you're using jQuery please update the tags on your question.

Comment: with the extra `var area` within the `do ... while` loop, are things referring to what you think they are?

Comment: you're also saying "is new-right less than old-left and old-right less than new-left" (as well as the same for bottom/top) - I'm guessing that this will never be true, it would be some quite oddly shaped divs... Suggest you look at your collision detection a bit more - it needs to be a bit more complex than this

Comment: I eventually went with @NiettheDarkAbsol's method and divided my page into a grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you used my algorithm, might as well post it as an answer!

As with many things, it is easier to cheat than to do exactly what you want to do.

Doing it the "proper" way would involve detecting collisions, which gets very tricky very fast.

However, here's a nice way to cheat at it:

1. Divide the area into a grid. Each grid square must be at least as big as your biggest element for this to work correctly.
2. For each element, pick a grid square. If that grid square hasn't been taken yet, place your element somewhere inside that grid square at random.

And... that's it! Now you are guaranteed to never have any collisions, and it looks pretty random because it is :)